# Stud Tyres - fixing the spikes on new tyres

Tags: tire, winter

[Schwalbe Snow Stud](http://www.schwalbe.co.uk/spikes/snow-stud/) tyres seem like a good winter commuting tyre in places that have only occasional snow/ice conditions. When they are fully inflated they can be used on normal roads and when run on low pressure they should provide good enough grip to cycle in icy conditions.

There is a following note on schwalbe website:

> In order to ensure that spikes are permanently fixed, tyres should be
>   run in for about 40km on asphalt, while avoiding any fast acceleration
>   or heavy braking.

**My question is:** Should this tyre be run on normal or low pressure for that initial 40km use on asphalt?

Comment: Maybe you should ask [Schwalbe](http://www.schwalbe.com/gbl/en/kontakt/formular/?ID_Seite=147&tn_mainPoint=Kontakt&tn_subPoint=).

Comment: [Nokian](http://www.suomityres.fi/winter.html) similarly say: "BREAK-IN ADVICE FOR STUDDED TYRES: Ride approx. 50km (30miles) on road surfaces. Avoid rapid acceleration and hard braking. Careful break-in will reduce stud loosing."

Answer (score 2):

I just bought these tires for Scottish winter, will chuck them on pretty soon. I think the idea for this 40km is to break the studs-in, to settle them into the tyre. 
So I would run them on medium pressure: the tyres are not overinflated, but also not on low pressure, sot the studs are engaged, but not 100%.

Answer (score 0):

If the studded tyre has studs only near the centerline of the tyre, I don't think the tyre pressure during the break-in period makes any difference. Each stud will hit the ground anyway.

More expensive and more offroad oriented studded tyres generally have studs also on the shoulders of the tyre. With these it makes sense to use unusually low tyre pressure during the break-in period, so that all studs hit the pavement despite riding very easy.